# Not able to get resource, classloader and class returns target path

Tags: java, file, properties, classloader

I am trying to get a properties file from `/src/main/resources/properties/` but for some reason the following code returns the path of target classes instead of src files. Can you please help?

```
System.out.println(PropTest.class.getResource("/properties/app.properties"));
System.out.println(PropTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("properties/app.properties"));
ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
System.out.println(classloader.getResource("properties/app.properties"));
PropTest prop=new PropTest();
System.out.println(prop.getClass().getResource("/properties/app.properties"));
```

Each line gives the same output which is:

```
file:/C:/Users/b./eclipse-workspace/ordermonitoring/target/classes/properties/app.properties
file:/C:/Users/b./eclipse-workspace/ordermonitoring/target/classes/properties/app.properties
file:/C:/Users/b./eclipse-workspace/ordermonitoring/target/classes/properties/app.properties
file:/C:/Users/b./eclipse-workspace/ordermonitoring/target/classes/properties/app.properties
```

Comment: This is exactly the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is correct. The resources will be loaded from class path. There wont be any src folder at runtime. What you can do is make the /src/main/resources as a source folder (if you are not using maven) so that the properties will be copied to target folder.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behaviour. For maven projects, while running, project is build and is kept in `target` folder always. you can also change this folder by some configuration. From this target folder, your application runs and thus your path shown in `classloader.getResource()` method. If you are building a jar , then your resources will be inside the jar and is always available. So `classloader.getResource()` will be working fine always.